# Efficient SQL from LINQ statement with joins and aggregate?

Tags: .net, sql, linq, entity-framework-4

I am trying to do what is a relatively basic SQL statement to join and group some tables and summarize with aggregate functions.  I would write it in SQL like this:

```
select
  p.LocationID,
  NumReadings = count(*),
  MinDate = min(t.[DateTime]),
  MaxDate = max(t.[DateTime])
from Station p inner join Data pd on p.LocationID = pd.ReadingLocationID
    inner join ApplicationDateTime t on t.ApplicationDateTimeID = pd.DateTimeID
group by p.LocationID
```

When I use the Linq statement below in EF4, it creates some hideous SQL (see very bottom).  Any better ways to do this?  Explicitly doing the joins instead of using the EF navigation properties makes it even worse.

I don't care about the aesthetics, but looking at the query execution, it takes 3-4x as long to execute the poorly formed SQL.

```
from s in Station
select new DataSummary
{
   ReadingLocationID = s.ReadingLocationID,
   StationIdentifier = s.StationIdentifier,
   NumReadings = s.Data.Count(),
   MinDateLoaded = s.Data.Min(d => d.ApplicationDateTime.DateTime),
   MaxDateLoaded = s.Data.Max(d => d.ApplicationDateTime.DateTime)
};
```

Here is the SQL (note: there are some additional complexities here, like a inherited relationship represented as another join, but that just causes another nesting level).

```
SELECT 
  [Project3].[LocationTypeID] AS [LocationTypeID], 
  [Project3].[ReadingLocationID] AS [ReadingLocationID], 
  [Project3].[LocationIdentifier] AS [LocationIdentifier], 
  [Project3].[C1] AS [C1], 
  CAST( [Project3].[C2] AS datetime2) AS [C2], 
  CAST( [Project3].[C3] AS datetime2) AS [C3]
FROM ( SELECT 
        [Project2].[ReadingLocationID] AS [ReadingLocationID], 
        [Project2].[LocationTypeID] AS [LocationTypeID], 
        [Project2].[LocationIdentifier] AS [LocationIdentifier], 
        [Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
        [Project2].[C2] AS [C2], 
        (SELECT 
           MAX([Extent7].[DateTime]) AS [A1]
           FROM  [dbo].[Data] AS [Extent6]
           INNER JOIN [dbo].[ApplicationDateTime] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent6].[DateTimeID] = [Extent7].[ApplicationDateTimeID]
           WHERE [Project2].[ReadingLocationID] = [Extent6].[ReadingLocationID]) AS [C3]
            FROM ( SELECT 
            [Project1].[ReadingLocationID] AS [ReadingLocationID], 
            [Project1].[LocationTypeID] AS [LocationTypeID], 
            [Project1].[LocationIdentifier] AS [LocationIdentifier], 
            [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
            (SELECT 
               MIN([Extent5].[DateTime]) AS [A1]
               FROM  [dbo].[Data] AS [Extent4]
               INNER JOIN [dbo].[ApplicationDateTime] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent4].[DateTimeID] = [Extent5].[ApplicationDateTimeID]
               WHERE [Project1].[ReadingLocationID] = [Extent4].[ReadingLocationID]) AS [C2]
               FROM ( SELECT 
                  [Extent1].[ReadingLocationID] AS [ReadingLocationID], 
                  [Extent1].[LocationTypeID] AS [LocationTypeID], 
                  [Extent1].[LocationIdentifier] AS [LocationIdentifier], 
                  (SELECT 
                        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                        FROM [dbo].[Data] AS [Extent3]
                        WHERE [Extent1].[ReadingLocationID] = [Extent3].[ReadingLocationID]) AS [C1]
                   FROM  [dbo].[ReadingLocation] AS [Extent1]
                   INNER JOIN [dbo].[Station] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ReadingLocationID] = [Extent2].[LocationID]
                   WHERE ([Extent1].[LocationTypeID] =  CAST( '1' AS int)) AND ([Extent2].[LineID] = 'ACBB3FDF-116C-4E8E-AA80-B925E4922AC8')
                   )  AS [Project1]
               )  AS [Project2]
)
```

Help! thanks.

Comment: Hmm that does look suspiciously overcomplicated. How does it look without the Min and Max?

Comment: Have you tested the query in Linq2Sql? In my experience it generates much better SQL.

Comment: without min and max, it removes two "levels".  It looks like it is really doing one query for each aggregate function.  It could also be that i'm doing the "max()" on a field from the joined table.  I'm already using EF for the project, so I can't really switch.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a different ORM?  Specifically a MicroOrm such as [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/), or [Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive) will let you write queries in SQL and get back .NET objects.

Both are Nuget Packages: [PetaPoco](http://nuget.org/packages/PetaPoco), [Massive](http://nuget.org/packages/Massive) so you can easily install them.

If you're comfortable writing SQL and would prefer to have control over your queries, they might be viable candidates.

Comment: Surely there's a better alternative here than to change his `ORM`, sledgehammer to crack a nut? Not having a go or anything I just think some Linq guru like @JonSkeet could make short work of this query.

Comment: Thanks for the info--nice to know about those ORM approaches.  However, I'm already tied into EF for this project, so I guess I was really asking if there was an alternative Linq approach that might yield more straightforward SQL.

Comment: @jrowe88 There might be a way, but one of the tradeoffs of EF is you don't get much control over what SQL is generated, and that's why I suggested a different ORM. I understand project constraints don't let you change at this time, but in my experience I never had any luck tuning the SQL from EF.

Comment: @mattytommo I'm sure there are ways to tune the LINQ, I was addressing the ability of having control over the SQL. In that case, changing the ORM probably is the best solution, since EF doesn't let you tune generated SQL much.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ can do a lot, but it definitely ain't magic.
Try to write your LINQ a bit more like you wrote your SQL. Define your joins.

This is what your LINQ-statement should look like:

```
Station
 .Join(Data, s => new { s.LocationID }, d => new { LocationID = d.ReadingLocationID }, (s,d) => new { s.ID, s.LocationID, d.DateTimeID })
 .Join(ApplicationDateTime, j1 => new { j1.DateTimeID }, t => new { DateTimeID = t.ApplicationDateTimeID }, (j1,t) => { j.ID, j.LocationID, t.DateTime })
 .Group(j2 => new { j2.ID, j2.LocationID })
 .Select(g => new DataSummary
   {
      StationIdentifier = g.Key.ID,
      ReadingLocationID = g.Key.LocationID,
      NumReadings = g.Count(),
      MinDateLoaded = g.Min(j2 => j2.DateTime),
      MaxDateLoaded = g.Max(j2 => j2.DateTime)
   });
```

NB: The code provided above is not tested!

Remember when creating a join in LINQ, the properties of the anonymous objects you use in your join should have the same names AND types. This took me some time to get my first join working.
Example: suppose the DateTimeID column on your Data table can be NULL and the column ApplicationDateTimeID on ApplicationDateTime can not be NULL. You should then change that join to:

```
.Join(ApplicationDateTime, j1 => new { j1.DateTimeID }, t => new { DateTimeID = (int?)t.ApplicationDateTimeID }, (j1,t) => { j.ID, j.LocationID, t.DateTime })
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try.  I do think by not joining on the 3rd table it is writing separate subqueries for each min and max aggregate then joining the result.